# WCF DataContract: Returning base class or inherited class depending on scenario

Tags: .net, wcf, inheritance

I am developing a WCF service designed to be consumed by non .NET clients, which performs a charge operation. I would like to be able to return either a base class DataContract or an inherited class DataContract depending on the use case.

So I have:

```
[DataContract]  
public class ChargeResponse  
{  
    [DataMember]  
    public string ID  

    [DataMember]  
    public string Description  
}
```

For successful operations, I would like to return an inherited type having an extra DataMember such as:

```
[DataContract]  
public class SuccessfulChargeResponse : ChargeResponse  
{  
    [DataMember]  
    public string TransactionID  
}
```

For all other cases I would return the bass class. Is this possible? Or should I just have the DataMember is the base class and return an empty value.

Comment: any specific reasoning as to this method? Have you perhaps considered `TransactionID` to simply be `[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]`

Comment: This is my first WCF service, so I guess I have a lot to learn :) If I use your method, will the parameter only be serialized if it has a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being overly complicated - you simply need to return a `ChargeResponse` that contains a `TransactionID`. If the operation was successful `TransactionID` will have a value, if it wasn't then `TransactionID` will be null. You can extend your class a little further to contain a flag or enumeration indicating the success, and whatever properties you need to indicate what the error was.

This is known as the request/response pattern and is quite common. Some (possibly very unexciting and not necessarily very new) links describing this:

- [MSDN: Message Patterns in WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff395349.aspx)
- [WCF Simplified Part 2: Message Exchange Patterns (MEPs)](http://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/05/25/wcf-simplified-part-2-message-exchange-patterns-meps/)
- [Patterns for Flexible WCF Services](http://www.designpatternsfor.net/default.aspx?pid=99)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. Please try considering below response
The key is to Use the attribute 'KnownType() on top of your Data Contract.

In detail:use [KnownType(typeof(SuccessfulChargeResponse))] attribute on top of base class. 
The attribute helps out the serialization engine to mark SuccessfulChargeResponse as a derived type of ChargeResponse base class.

Now that the DataContract is marked with its derived types, the response can be of either base type or derived type

Hope this helps. Good Luck :)

refer this link for reference 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Comment: Also see [ServiceKnownTypeSttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I take it this is a SOAP-based service? If so the correct way to alert consumers of a fault or non-success condition which they are obliged to handle is to expose a fault contract on the service definition. Then you can simply throw an exception and have the consumer catch the exception as they would if the service operation was an in-process method.

To do this use the FaultContract attribute in your service definition:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyChargeServiceExceptionType))]
ChargeResponse Charge(ChargeRequest request);
```